# An error when creating a table in SQL database using Visual Studio

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio

I am trying to create 3 tables in SQL database. For each of the three tables, I get the following error `SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '#'. Expecting '(' or SELECT`. See the following screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaxVD.png)

I get the error when I define the varchar size and I also get it with the name of columns that are foreign keys to other tables such as `Product_ID`.

Do you have any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Please mention which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems fine. There is a misplaced comma(,) after second foreign key reference. Remove it. Here goes your code.

```
create table orders(
ID varchar(20) primary key,
product_id int not null,
customer_id int not null,
quantity int not null,
status_id varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (product_id)references product(id),
foreign key (customer_id)references customer(id)
)
```

Comment: Have you tried exactly same code I have provided? Or you are trying to create table from another table?. Please confirm.